# Função inserir fim lista ligada

Tags: c

Galera não estou conseguindo desenvolver essa função.

```
bool inserir_fim (tipo_lista * p, tipo_lista * novo_no)
{



}
```

Comment: Tem exemplos aqui: http://www.cprogressivo.net/2013/10/Lista-simplesmente-encadeada-com-cabeca-em-C-Inserindo-nos-no-inicio-e-fim.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct tipo_lista{
    int info;
    struct tipo_lista * prox;
};

typedef struct tipo_lista tipo_lista;

tipo_lista * cria_no (int valor)
{
    tipo_lista * novo;
    novo = (tipo_lista *)malloc(sizeof(tipo_lista));
    novo -> info = valor;
    novo -> prox = NULL;
    return novo;
}

bool inserir_fim (tipo_lista * p, tipo_lista * novo_no)
{
    if (!p) {
        return false;
    }

    while (p->prox) {
        p = p->prox;
    }

    p->prox = novo_no;

    return true;
}

int main(void) {
    tipo_lista * p = cria_no(1);
    inserir_fim(p, cria_no(2));
    printf("%d %d\n", p->info, p->prox->info);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não seria true or false o retorno?

Comment: Acho que sim, talvez 0 e 1 funcione, mas é melhor true e false.

Comment: E como eu testo isso na main?

Comment: Você vai precisar da função de criar um novo nó para testar essa função.

Comment: tipo assim: https://pastebin.com/vyGn1mJm

Comment: Editei a resposta com o main.

Comment: deu erro nesse printf da main

Comment: Que erro que deu? Eu estou testando aqui: https://ideone.com/6h1WsX

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57338/discussion-between-andre-and-waterscroll).